# Multiple instance of this Accordion on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to have multiple instance of this accordion on the same page. Here is a link to the fiddle [jsfiddle.net/r817L7rv/](http://jsfiddle.net/r817L7rv/)

The second accordion is the same as first one duplicated with different heading text or content. Below is the code. See the fiddle External Resources for dependencies.

```
(function($) {

// cache some values
var cache   = {
        idx_expanded    : -1, // the index of the current expanded slice
        sliceH          : 0,  // the default slice's height 
        current         : 0,  // controls the current slider position
        totalSlices     : 0   // total number of slices
    },
    aux     = {
        // triggered when we click a slice. If the slice is expanded,
        // we close it, otherwise we open it..
        selectSlice     : function( $el, $slices, $navNext, $navPrev, settings ) {

            return $.Deferred(
                function( dfd ) {

                    var expanded    = $el.data('expanded'),
                        pos         = $el.data('position'),

                        itemHeight, othersHeight,

                        $others     = $slices.not( $el );

                    // if it's opened.. 
                    if( expanded ) {
                        $el.data( 'expanded', false );
                        cache.idx_expanded  = -1;

                        // the default values of each slices's height
                        itemHeight  = cache.sliceH;
                        othersHeight= cache.sliceH;

                        // hide the content div
                        $el.find('.va-content','.za-content').hide();

                        // control the navigation buttons visibility
                        if( aux.canSlideUp( $slices, settings ) )
                            $navPrev.fadeIn();
                        else
                            $navPrev.fadeOut();

                        if( aux.canSlideDown( $slices, settings ) )
                            $navNext.fadeIn();
                        else
                            $navNext.fadeOut();
                    }
                    // if it's closed..
                    else {
                        $el.data( 'expanded', true );
                        cache.idx_expanded  = $el.index();
                        $others.data( 'expanded', false );
                        // the current slice's height
                        itemHeight  = settings.expandedHeight;
                        // the height the other slices will have
                        othersHeight= Math.ceil( ( settings.accordionH - settings.expandedHeight ) / ( settings.visibleSlices - 1 ) );

                        // control the navigation buttons visibility
                        if( cache.idx_expanded > 0 )
                            $navPrev.fadeIn();
                        else    
                            $navPrev.fadeOut();

                        if( cache.idx_expanded < cache.totalSlices - 1 )
                            $navNext.fadeIn();  
                        else
                            $navNext.fadeOut();
                    }

                    // the animation parameters for the clicked slice
                    var animParam   = { 
                                        height  : itemHeight + 'px', 
                                        opacity : 1,
                                        top     : ( pos - 1 ) * othersHeight + 'px'
                                      };

                    // animate the clicked slice and also its title (<h3>)
                    $el.stop()
                       .animate( animParam, settings.animSpeed, settings.animEasing, function() {
                            if( !expanded )
                                $el.find('.va-content','za-content').fadeIn( settings.contentAnimSpeed );
                       })
                       .find('.va-title','za-title')
                       .stop()
                       .animate({
                            lineHeight  : cache.sliceH + 'px'
                       }, settings.animSpeed, settings.animEasing );    

                    // animate all the others
                    $others.each(function(i){
                        var $other  = $(this),
                            posother= $other.data('position'),
                            t;

                        if( expanded )
                            t   = ( posother - 1 ) * othersHeight ;
                        else {
                            if( posother < pos )
                                t   = ( posother - 1 ) * othersHeight ;
                            else
                                t   = ( ( posother - 2 ) * othersHeight ) + settings.expandedHeight;
                        }

                        $other.stop()
                              .animate( {
                                    top     : t + 'px',
                                    height  : othersHeight + 'px',
                                    opacity : ( expanded ) ? 1 : settings.animOpacity
                              }, settings.animSpeed, settings.animEasing, dfd.resolve )
                              .find('.va-title','za-title')
                              .stop()
                              .animate({
                                    lineHeight  : othersHeight + 'px'
                              }, settings.animSpeed, settings.animEasing )
                              .end()
                              .find('.va-content','za-content')
                              .hide();
                    });
                }
            ).promise();

        },
        // triggered when clicking the navigation buttons / mouse scrolling
        navigate        : function( dir, $slices, $navNext, $navPrev, settings ) {
            // if animating return
            if( $slices.is(':animated') ) 
                return false;

            // all move up / down one position
            // if settings.savePositions is false, then we need to close any expanded slice before sliding
            // otherwise we slide, and the next one will open automatically
            var $el;

            if( cache.idx_expanded != -1 && !settings.savePositions ) {
                $el = $slices.eq( cache.idx_expanded );

                $.when( aux.selectSlice( $el, $slices, $navNext, $navPrev, settings ) ).done(function(){
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    aux.slide( dir, $slices, $navNext, $navPrev, settings );
                    }, 10);
                });
            }
            else {
                aux.slide( dir, $slices, $navNext, $navPrev, settings );
            }   
        },
        slide           : function( dir, $slices, $navNext, $navPrev, settings ) {
            // control if we can navigate.
            // control the navigation buttons visibility.
            // the navigation will behave differently for the cases we have all the slices closed, 
            // and when one is opened. It will also depend on settings.savePositions 
            if( cache.idx_expanded === -1 || !settings.savePositions ) {
            if( dir === 1 && cache.current + settings.visibleSlices >= cache.totalSlices )
                return false;
            else if( dir === -1 && cache.current === 0 )
                return false;

            if( dir === -1 && cache.current === 1 )
                $navPrev.fadeOut();
            else
                $navPrev.fadeIn();

                if( dir === 1 && cache.current + settings.visibleSlices === cache.totalSlices - 1 )
                $navNext.fadeOut();
            else
                $navNext.fadeIn();
            }
            else {
                if( dir === 1 && cache.idx_expanded === cache.totalSlices - 1 )
                    return false;
                else if( dir === -1 && cache.idx_expanded === 0 )
                    return false;

                if( dir === -1 && cache.idx_expanded === 1 )
                    $navPrev.fadeOut();
                else
                    $navPrev.fadeIn();

                if( dir === 1 && cache.idx_expanded === cache.totalSlices - 2 )
                    $navNext.fadeOut();
                else
                    $navNext.fadeIn();
            }

            var $currentSlice   = $slices.eq( cache.idx_expanded ),
                $nextSlice,
                t;

            ( dir === 1 ) ? $nextSlice = $currentSlice.next() : $nextSlice = $currentSlice.prev();

            // if we cannot slide up / down, then we just call the selectSlice for the previous / next slice
            if( ( dir === 1 && !aux.canSlideDown( $slices, settings ) ) || 
                ( dir === -1 && !aux.canSlideUp( $slices, settings ) ) ) {
                aux.selectSlice( $nextSlice, $slices, $navNext, $navPrev, settings );
                return false;
            }

            // if we slide down, the top and position of each slice will decrease
            if( dir === 1 ) {
                cache.current++;
                t = '-=' + cache.sliceH;
                pos_increment   = -1;
            }
            else {
                cache.current--;
                t = '+=' + cache.sliceH;
                pos_increment   = 1;
            }

            $slices.each(function(i) {
                var $slice      = $(this),
                    pos         = $slice.data('position');

                // all closed or savePositions is false
                if( !settings.savePositions || cache.idx_expanded === -1 )
                    $slice.stop().animate({top : t}, settings.animSpeed, settings.animEasing);
                else {
                    var itemHeight, othersHeight;

                    // if the slice is the one we should open..
                    if( i === $nextSlice.index() ) {
                        $slice.data( 'expanded', true );
                        cache.idx_expanded  = $slice.index();
                        itemHeight          = settings.expandedHeight;
                        othersHeight        = ( settings.accordionH - settings.expandedHeight ) / ( settings.visibleSlices - 1 );

                        $slice.stop()
                              .animate({
                                    height      : itemHeight + 'px', 
                                    opacity     : 1,
                                    top         : ( dir === 1 ) ? ( pos - 2 ) * othersHeight + 'px' : pos * othersHeight + 'px'
                              }, settings.animSpeed, settings.animEasing, function() {
                                    $slice.find('.va-content','za-content').fadeIn( settings.contentAnimSpeed );
                              })
                              .find('.va-title','za-title')
                              .stop()
                              .animate({
                                    lineHeight  : cache.sliceH + 'px'
                              }, settings.animSpeed, settings.animEasing );
                    }
                    // if the slice is the one opened, lets close it
                    else if( $slice.data('expanded') ){
                        // collapse

                        $slice.data( 'expanded', false );
                        othersHeight        = ( settings.accordionH - settings.expandedHeight ) / ( settings.visibleSlices - 1 );

                        $slice.stop()
                              .animate({ 
                                    height  : othersHeight + 'px', 
                                    opacity : settings.animOpacity,
                                    top     : ( dir === 1 ) ? '-=' + othersHeight : '+=' + settings.expandedHeight
                              }, settings.animSpeed, settings.animEasing )
                              .find('.va-title','za-title')
                              .stop()
                              .animate({
                                    lineHeight  : othersHeight + 'px'
                              }, settings.animSpeed, settings.animEasing )
                              .end()
                              .find('.va-content','za-content')
                              .hide();        
                    }
                    // all the others..
                    else {
                        $slice.data( 'expanded', false );
                        othersHeight        = ( settings.accordionH - settings.expandedHeight ) / ( settings.visibleSlices - 1 );

                        $slice.stop()
                              .animate({ 
                                    top     : ( dir === 1 ) ? '-=' + othersHeight : '+=' + othersHeight
                              }, settings.animSpeed, settings.animEasing );
                    }
                }
                // change the slice's position
                $slice.data().position += pos_increment;
            });
        },
        canSlideUp      : function( $slices, settings ) {
            var $first          = $slices.eq( cache.current );

            if( $first.index() !== 0 )
                return true;
        },
        canSlideDown    : function( $slices, settings ) {
            var $last           = $slices.eq( cache.current + settings.visibleSlices - 1 );

            if( $last.index() !== cache.totalSlices - 1 )
                return true;
        }
    },
    methods = {
        init        : function( options ) {

            if( this.length ) {

                var settings = {
                    // the accordion's width
                    accordionW      : 705,
                    // the accordion's height
                    accordionH      : 610,
                    // number of visible slices
                    visibleSlices   : 3,
                    // the height of a opened slice
                    // should not be more than accordionH
                    expandedHeight  : 450,
                    // speed when opening / closing a slice
                    animSpeed       : 250,
                    // easing when opening / closing a slice
                    animEasing      : 'jswing',
                    // opacity value for the collapsed slices
                    animOpacity     : 0.2,
                    // time to fade in the slice's content
                    contentAnimSpeed: 900,
                    // if this is set to false, then before
                    // sliding we collapse any opened slice
                    savePositions   : true
                };

                return this.each(function() {

                    // if options exist, lets merge them with our default settings
                    if ( options ) {
                        $.extend( settings, options );
                    }

                    var $el             = $(this),
                        // the accordion's slices
                        $slices         = $el.find('div.va-slice','div.za-slice'),
                        // the navigation buttons
                        $navNext        = $el.find('span.va-nav-next','span.za-nav-next'),
                        $navPrev        = $el.find('span.va-nav-prev','span.za-nav-prev');

                    // each slice's height
                    cache.sliceH        = Math.ceil( settings.accordionH / settings.visibleSlices );

                    // total slices
                    cache.totalSlices   = $slices.length;

                    // control some user config parameters
                    if( settings.expandedHeight > settings.accordionH )
                        settings.expandedHeight = settings.accordionH;
                    else if( settings.expandedHeight <= cache.sliceH )
                        settings.expandedHeight = cache.sliceH + 50; // give it a minimum

                    // set the accordion's width & height
                    $el.css({
                        width   : settings.accordionW + 'px',
                        height  : settings.accordionH + 'px'
                    });

                    // show / hide $navNext 
                    if( settings.visibleSlices < cache.totalSlices  )
                        $navNext.show();

                    // set the top & height for each slice.
                    // also save the position of each one.
                    // as we navigate, the first one in the accordion
                    // will have position 1 and the last settings.visibleSlices.
                    // finally set line-height of the title (<h3>)
                    $slices.each(function(i){
                        var $slice  = $(this);
                        $slice.css({
                            top     : i * cache.sliceH + 'px',
                            height  : cache.sliceH + 'px'
                        }).data( 'position', (i + 1) );
                    })
                    .children('.va-title','za-title')
                    .css( 'line-height', cache.sliceH + 'px' );

                    // click event
                    $slices.bind('click.vaccordion', function(e) {
                        // only if we have more than 1 visible slice. 
                        // otherwise we will just be able to slide.
                        if( settings.visibleSlices > 1 ) {
                            var $el         = $(this);
                            aux.selectSlice( $el, $slices, $navNext, $navPrev, settings );
                        }
                    });

                    // navigation events
                    $navNext.bind('click.vaccordion', function(e){
                        aux.navigate( 1, $slices, $navNext, $navPrev, settings );
                    });

                    $navPrev.bind('click.vaccordion', function(e){
                        aux.navigate( -1, $slices, $navNext, $navPrev, settings );
                    });

                    // adds events to the mouse
                    $el.bind('mousewheel.vaccordion', function(e, delta) {
                        if(delta > 0) {
                            aux.navigate( -1, $slices, $navNext, $navPrev, settings );
                        }   
                        else {
                            aux.navigate( 1, $slices, $navNext, $navPrev, settings );
                        }   
                        return false;
                    });

                });
            }
        }
    };

$.fn.vaccordion = function(method) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.vaccordion' );
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You're referencing your accordions by `ID` which is an unique identifier. And unique means here unique. http://jsfiddle.net/g6w1ydf8/

Comment: oops. You called it! Tired mind here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID Must be unique, try changing the `id` of the seconde element:

```
<div id="va-accordion" class="va-container">
...
</div>
<div id="va-accordion2" class="va-container"> //Add number 2 on the id
...
</div>
```

And on the Jquery function use

```
(function ($) {
    $('#va-accordion, #va-accordion2').vaccordion();//Add the other id
}(jQuery));
```

Check Your [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r817L7rv/6/)

Now if you want to improve your code you can also reference the `classname` instead of the id's

```
(function ($) {
    $('.va-container').vaccordion();
}(jQuery));
```

Check Another [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r817L7rv/7/)

Comment: Or even more simple: `$('.va-container').vaccordion();` http://jsfiddle.net/r817L7rv/8/

Comment: yep @gearsdigital I was adding that on the post when you comment XD